# How to remove prefix and namespace in SOAPElement?

Tags: java, xml, dom, wsdl, saaj

Collogues, i have cycle which create soap xml with nessesary structure (don't ask about the structure)

```
log.info("Body elements: ");
NodeList nodeList = body.getElementsByTagName("*") ;
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        log.info(node.getNodeName());

        if (node.getNodeName().equals("ns2:request")) {
            log.info("Set namespace and prefix for " + node.getNodeName());
            SOAPElement childX = (SOAPElement) node;
            childX.removeNamespaceDeclaration(childX.getPrefix()) ;
            childX.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns3", "http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws");
            childX.setPrefix("ns3");
        }

        else {                        
            if (node.getNodeName().equals("ns2:in") ) {
                log.info("Remove namespace for  " + node.getNodeName());
                SOAPElement childX = (SOAPElement) node;
                childX.removeNamespaceDeclaration(childX.getPrefix()) ;
                childX.addNamespaceDeclaration("", "");
                childX.setPrefix("");
            }

            SOAPElement childX = (SOAPElement) node;
            childX.removeNamespaceDeclaration(childX.getPrefix()) ;
            childX.setPrefix("");
        }
    }
}
```

As a result I receive xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns3:request xmlns:ns3="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">
         <in xmlns="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">
            <requestHeader>
```

My question is how to remove only `xmlns="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws"` from  `<in>` element and receive:

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ns3:request xmlns:ns3="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">
             <in>
                <requestHeader>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to config xml element:

```
    /*Config body elements*/
                while (itBodyElements.hasNext()) 
                {  
                  Object o = itBodyElements.next();
                  SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = (SOAPBodyElement) o;
                  log.info("Elements from 'Body' element = " + bodyElement.getLocalName() );

                  Iterator it2 = bodyElement.getChildElements();
                         while (it2.hasNext()) 
                         { 
                              Object requestElement = it2.next();
                              SOAPBodyElement bodyRequest = (SOAPBodyElement) requestElement;
                              log.info("  Elements from '"+ bodyElement.getLocalName() + "' element = " + bodyRequest.getLocalName()); 
                              log.info("  Delete namespace from IN element " + bodyRequest.getLocalName());
                              bodyRequest.removeNamespaceDeclaration(bodyRequest.getPrefix());
                              bodyRequest.setPrefix("");

                               Iterator it3 = bodyRequest.getChildElements();
                                    while (it3.hasNext())
                                    { //work with other elements
```

But it has not effect to 'in' element. After run i still have:
`<in xmlns="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">`

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem by calling ws as next:

```
getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
                "URL",
                request,
                new WebServiceMessageCallback()
                { public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {

                        SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage)message;

                        SOAPMessage soapMessage = UtilsClass.createSOAPMessage(in);

                        saajSoapMessage.setSaajMessage(soapMessage);

                }

                } 
                );
```

Method **createSOAPMessage** configure soap message using javax.xml.soap library.

Comment: You know that the 2 snippets of xml do mean something different right? in the first `<requestHeader>` will be in the namespace `http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws`. In the second it will be in the default-namespace (whatever the default namespace was before)

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the attribute using something like

```
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nList = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/Envelope/Body/request/in", body, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); ++i) {
        Element e = (Element) nList.item(i);
        e.removeAttribute("xmlns");
    }
```

The following test shows that it does work.

```
@Test
public void removeXmlns() throws Exception {
    String xml = "" +
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "      <ns3:request xmlns:ns3=\"http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws\">\n" +
            "         <in xmlns=\"http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws\">\n" +
            "            <requestHeader>\n" +
            "            </requestHeader>\n" +
            "         </in>\n" +
            "      </ns3:request>\n" +
            "   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";


    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = builder.parse(ResourceUtils.getFile("/soaptest.xml").getAbsolutePath());
    Element body = document.getDocumentElement();

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nList = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/Envelope/Body/request/in", body, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); ++i) {
        Element e = (Element) nList.item(i);
        e.removeAttribute("xmlns");
    }
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(domSource, result);
    logger.info("XML IN String format is: \n" + writer.toString());     
}
```

The output is

```
2015-11-26-11-46-24[]::[main]:(demo.TestCode.removeXmlns(TestCode.java:174):174):INFO :TestCode:XML IN String format is: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns3:request xmlns:ns3="http://dfg/Ws">
         <in>
            <requestHeader>
            </requestHeader>
         </in>
      </ns3:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: This won't work because in the DOM the elements will still be in the `http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws` namespace.

Comment: The example incoming xml has <ns3:request xmlns:ns3="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws"> and <in xmlns="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">.  The question was how to remove the second namespace xmlns, which is what my code example does.

Comment: You are using namespace unaware parsing, but the OP uses SAAJ which always processes messages with a namespace aware parser.

Comment: Must have misunderstood the question then, didn't see anything about SAAJ.  Just answered what I thought was the question.

Comment: Well, the question is tagged with "saaj", the title refers to SOAPElement and the code uses methods specific to SAAJ...

Comment: There are no methods in the code specific to SAAJ.  There are alternatives.  My solution supported the question.  I might add that your understanding of the question and especially the xml input differs from the originators question and the xml input.

Comment: Of course there are methods specific to SAAJ in the code provided by the OP. Look more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your code gets the following XML as input:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:request xmlns:ns3="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">
         <ns2:in>
            <ns2:requestHeader>
```

And you want to transform it into the following XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns3:request xmlns:ns3="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">
         <in>
            <requestHeader>
```

In this case, adjusting the namespace declarations and namespace prefixes is not enough because in the DOM the `in` and `requestHeader` elements will still be in the `http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws` namespace. That is because the namespace URI of a DOM element is determined at creation/parse time and doesn't change when namespace declarations are added or removed later. When the DOM is serialized, the serializer will automatically generate the necessary namespace declarations to make sure that the elements in the output effectively have the namespaces they had in the DOM. That is why you get `xmlns="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws"` in the output, although that namespace declaration is not present in the DOM.

What you really need to do is to change the namespace URI for these elements. Unfortunately, DOM nodes don't have a `setNamespaceURI` method and you need to use `Document.renameNode` instead.

Comment: Andreas Veithen, i added update. Could you take a look?

Comment: Your update doesn't take into account what I explained in my answer. It's therefore not surprising that it still doesn't work.